# Expressions in markdown using knitr

Tags: r, expression, markdown, knitr

I'm trying to use an inline expression in a .Rmd markdown file. I'm converting the .Rmd file to a PDF using Pandoc. The contents of my file is like this:

````
Report 
========================================================

This is my text and this is my expression 100km^2

```{r}
summary(cars)
```
````

I expected 100km^s to render normally, but it renders literally as '100km^2'. How can I get the expression to render?

Comment: your expression itself is incorrect; knit(text="This is my text and this is my expression `r expression(100 * km^2)`") would be better, but knitr doesn't know what to do with an expression to display inline, which it sees as a list with multiple elements.

Comment: also, why do you need `expression()`?

Comment: Post edited: 100km^2 renders if converting to html with knitr, but is literal when converting to PDF with Pandoc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use latex math mode for this,

```
knit(text="$100 km^2$",output="test.md")
pandoc("test.md", format="latex")
```

gives me:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Simply wrap the expression in `$` characters -- that is, `$100km^2$` instead of `100km^2`.